# $scope variable shared across ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following html

```
<section class="result" ng-repeat="record in results | orderBy: sortRecordByTimestamp" ng-init="highlights(record)" ng-class="level">
          <!-- some stuff -->
</section>
```

My scope has `$scope.level = ''` on init. Functions are:

```
function highlights(record) {

  // will contain more logic
  console.log('Highlighting...');
  level(record);

}
```

and

```
function level(record) {

  $scope.spreadsheet.forEach(function(row) {
    if (row.Name.indexOf(record.event) > -1) {
      $scope.level = 'level' + row.Level;
    }
  });

}
```

It correctly sets the `$scope.level` like it is supposed to, however, it is shared across all my results.

Isn't `ng-repeat` creating child scopes, with primitives being overwritten?

**EDIT:**

Changed the html:

```
<section class="result" ng-repeat="record in results | orderBy: sortRecordByTimestamp" ng-class="level(record)">
  <!-- code -->
</section>
```

and the js:

```
$scope.level = function(record) {

  $scope.spreadsheet.forEach(function(row) {
    if (row.Name.indexOf(record.event) > -1) {
      console.log('Highlighting: level' + row.Level);
      return 'level' + row.Level;
    }
  });

}
```

It is logging correct values, however, ng-class is never set. Why?

**EDIT 2:**

To clarify what I am trying to do:

`$scope.spreadsheet` contains data to compare to `record` data. Match can be found in 3 instances, each enumerated in `row.Level` depending on `row.Name`. So `level(record)` returns a css class of **level1**, **level2** or **level3**.

These have a `background: /* color */` property set to them. So each row that has `record.event` found in the `row.Name` (they don't match exactly, that's why no `===`) is colored based on which level of importance it is given.

The first time I tried to make the child scopes inherit the `$scope.level` property and determine it on element creation (that's why `ng-init`), then I made `$scope.level` a function that returns the level. However, it fires on ALL records with the result of the last iteration.

How do I make determining the level separate for each record?

Comment: this isn't really the right way to use `ng-init`.  The purpose of `ng-init` is to create an **alias** for special `ng-repeat` properties like `$first`, `$last`, `$index`, etc..  It *is not* for establishing variables, or running a function.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: i know, i tried to come up with a different solution to this problem before... check the edit, seems neater, however, does not work

Comment: what *exactly* are you trying to accomplish? It would be much easier to help you find a working solution with a more complete picture of your problem.  what is the `level` css class, and what are you anticipating as a result?

Answer (score 2):

`ng-repeat` doesn't create an isolated scope, it does create an child scope which is prototypically inherited from its parent scope. If you look at `ng-repeat` API you will found that `ng-repeat` directive has `scope: true` in it, which is responsible for creating prototypically inherited scope.

To access the property of parent scope inside child scope, you should have declared `object` type, so that as per dot rule you could access its child properties inside child. If you are using `primitive` types then you should have mention `$parent.` to get access to parent scope variable.

There are various way provided by `ng-repeat` API to keep track on which which element you are, `$index` in place on which `index` element you are in.

> `$index`  number  iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1)
>
> `$first`  boolean true if the repeated element is first in the
>   iterator.
>
> `$middle` boolean true if the repeated element is between
>   the first and last in the iterator.
>
> `$last`   boolean true if the
>   repeated element is last in the iterator.
>
> `$even`   boolean `true` if
>   the iterator position $index is even (otherwise false).
>
> `$odd`    boolean true if the iterator position $index is odd (otherwise false).

Answer (score -1):

you can create a common controller and define a scope variable in this controller and then you can give reference of common controller into that controller file where you want to get this variable.